# Showing that $n1_{ \lbrace U<1/n \rbrace}$ converges to $0$ almost surely

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $U \sim \text{Uniform}[0, 1]$ and $X_n = n1_{\lbrace U< 1/n \rbrace}$. I want to show that $X_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely.

My attempt:

I use Fatou's Lemma with the reasoning that if I can show that 
$$
\mathbb{P}(\liminf \lbrace  n1_{\lbrace U< 1/n \rbrace}>\epsilon \rbrace) = 0
$$ 
then I have shown that the event $\lbrace  n1_{\lbrace U< 1/n \rbrace}>\epsilon \rbrace$ will almost surely never happen, and hence convergence in probability. So..
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\liminf \lbrace  n1_{\lbrace U< 1/n \rbrace}>\epsilon \rbrace) &\leq \liminf \mathbb{P}(\lbrace  n1_{\lbrace U< 1/n \rbrace}>\epsilon \rbrace)\\
&=\liminf \mathbb{P}(U\le 1/n)\\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$ 
I am however not completely sure about the application of Fatou's lemma here. Maybe there is a more direct way as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\omega \in (0,1]$, then for $n > 1/\omega$ you have $X_n(\omega)=0$. So we have pointwise convergence on $(0,1]$. Since $\{ 0 \}$ has probability zero, we have almost sure convergence.

Comment: Beat me by $50$ secs :).

Answer (score 1):

The measure of the set where $X_n$ converges to $0$ can be calculated as follows:

Let $x \in (0,1]$. Then choose $N$ such that $\dfrac{1}{N} < x$. Then, $X_n(x)=0$ for all $n>N$. So, the set of points where $X_n$ converges to $0$ has measure $1$, and hence you get almost sure convergence.